# Accessing function's caller type

Tags: c++

Now, I know this question appears multiple times, e.g. [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/11088/). However, for beginners answer for such question is simply "don't use that, it's bad programming", I think it's the best solution in my use case.

But to the point: I would like to access type of the function's caller in C++. Tldr, I want to use it in `typeid(CALLER)`. Below follows details about my use case

I have an object, let's call it `AnalyzedObject`, which is a subject of evaluation by multiple (polymorphic) `Evaluator`s, whether it's accepted or rejected. All in all, I want `AnalyzedObject` itself to know, whether it's accepted or rejected, but the thing is that `Evaluator`s' voting is not something that's calculated straightforwardly and the impact of each `Evaluator` depends on its type. So, I have something that more or less looks like:

```cpp
struct AnalyzedObject {
  unordered_map<type_index, bool> votes;
  bool accepted;
  // other data...

  void add_vote(bool vote) {
    votes[????]=vote;
  }
}

class Evaluator {
  void Evaluate(AnalyzedObject& obj) {
    obj.add_vote(vote());
  }

  virtual void vote() = 0;
}

class VotingPolicy {
  bool Elect(unordered_map<type_index, bool> votes);
}

AnalyzedObject object;
vector<Evaluator*> evaluators;
for(auto evaluator : evaluators) {
  evaluator->Evaluate(object);
}
VotingPolicy policy;
object.accepted = policy.Elect(object.votes);
```

So, the question is: **How should I fill the question marks (`????`), to do the job here?**

I know, that I could do some workarounds, like for example

```cpp
void add_vote(Evaluator& type, bool vote) {
  votes[typeid(decltype(evaluator))]=vote;
}
```

or

```cpp
template<class T>
void add_vote(bool vote) {
  votes[typeid(T)]=vote;
}
```

but to be pedantic about API-correctness, the argument there will always be `this`, thus it should be omitted...

Anyhow, if you happen to have any other idea how to solve my issue, feel free to propose something different!

Comment: No, a function should produce the same output on the same inputs. However, you can require an input that tells the function what it needs to know. It's not really a "workaround" as you called it -- it is fundamental to what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: You could derive all analyzed objects from a common base (optionally polymorphic).

Comment: @KennyOstrom Sure, I'm aware that function output has to be deterministic, thus produce the same output for the same inputs, but I think why not add another dimension here: let function's output depend on its inputs and on whoever calls it. After all, that policy occurs e.g. in _template method_ design pattern and is natural for polymorphic issues...

Comment: If you don't provide information about the caller to the function, where does/should the information come from? Callstack? (BTW the virtual function vote should return bool I think)

Comment: I'm confused by your function storing all its state in intermediate steps stored in other objects. Policy::Elect should pass the AnalyzedObject to each Evaluator, and use their responses to give the result. Instead, you seem to be storing its internal state inside AnalyzedObject, and then having Policy look at it later. And why do the voters have to vote without access to the thing they are voting on?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a voting policy that takes a collection of voters and returns a yes/no vote on some object. I think this example does a good job of putting the logic inside the function, and passing what is needed to each function.

```
#include <vector>

// abstract base class (interface) for AnalyzedObject
class AnalyzedObject {
public:
    AnalyzedObject() {}
    virtual ~AnalyzedObject() {}

    // provide getters for all the things an evaluator may consider
    virtual bool Do_you_support_key_feature_one() const = 0;
    virtual bool Do_you_support_key_feature_two() const = 0;
    virtual int YearsService() const = 0;
    virtual int Price() const = 0;
};

// abstract base class (interface) for voter/evaluator
class Evaluator {
public:
    Evaluator();
    virtual ~Evaluator() {}
    virtual bool vote(const AnalyzedObject&) = 0;
};

// raw pointers here is ill-advised
typedef std::vector<Evaluator*> voter_panel_type;

// abstract base class (interface) for voting policy
class VotingPolicy {
public:
    VotingPolicy();
    virtual ~VotingPolicy() {}
    virtual bool vote(voter_panel_type, const AnalyzedObject&) = 0;
};

// implement a voting policy
class MajorityRules : public VotingPolicy {
    bool vote(std::vector<Evaluator*> evaluators, const AnalyzedObject &object) {
        voter_panel_type::size_type yes = 0;
        for (auto voter : evaluators) {
            if (voter->vote(object))
                yes += 1;
        }
        return yes * 2 > evaluators.size();
    }
};
```